# How to use dls:document-manage in MLCP bulk operation in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

We tried to do [dls:document-manage](https://docs.marklogic.com/dls:document-manage) for our documents stored in Marklogic database. We tried with MLCP bulk operation to load multiple documents from file system and how to simultaneously do the [dls:document-manage](https://docs.marklogic.com/dls:document-manage) for all these files.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use a CPF action to put the documents into management via to [dls:document-manage()](https://docs.marklogic.com/dls:document-manage) function when the document is added?  It seems that it might be relatively straight-forward to do given the [example](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/quickStart) in the documentation. You would only need to make sure the user executing the MLCP bulk load has the *dls-user* role.

Answer (score 2):

You may also call an XQuery script while ingesting documents into MarkLogic server which can put your documents into DLS